# Does my HDD still work after almost 10years not in use?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, truecrypt, hard-drive-recovery, hardware-detection

I found my HDD HD250HJ from Samsung after 10years.
The whole HDD is encrypted with TrueCrypt 7.1 and is a hidden volume.

When I plugged in my HDD it's not visible in the explorer nor in TrueCrypt.
Is this because it's a hidden volume or because it's not working anymore?

Comment: Does the hard drive power/spin up properly (no clicking, etc.)? Does it show up in device manager or disk management in Windows (you only mentioned Explorer - and assuming you are on Windows)?

Comment: The HDD is covered up, so it's not visible if the HDD is spinning.
The first time I plugged it in, it made noises and gave some beeps like when the computer boots up.

It's not visible in the disk management in Windows, but the device managers shows a "XvD" in the Hard drives section

Comment: The first place to start is always the firmware (BIOS or uEFI). If not detected there then it won't be in the OS, obviously. In that case it's probably game over for the HDD but it can also be due a failed controller in the board or something between (cable, adapter,...) or any combination of this factors. What @SamForbis asked was about an audible spin-up without any other noises that automatically indicate drive failure (we know how HDDs look like).

Comment: If it made noises before when powered up, but now it does nothing when powered up, then I believe it is dead.

Answer (score 1):

> I found my HDD HD250HJ from Samsung after 10years. The whole HDD is
> encrypted with TrueCrypt 7.1 and is a hidden volume.

A HDD is a motor spinning a platter and another stepper motor running the heads.

If any of these get stuck from non-use, the drive will not start.

Ten years of non-use is lots of time to stick.

I have seen numerous old drives fail this way.

> When I plugged in my HDD it's not visible in the explorer nor in
> TrueCrypt. Is this because .... it's not working anymore?

Most likely.   It is an old design in any event so not worth much.

Comment: If I open up the HDD can I fix this manually so it's not stuck anymore?

Comment: NO.  That will definitely not work. The drive will be useless once opened.

Comment: You can build a clean room box, then use that to open the drive and see if the heads are stuck. You should be able to hear the hard drive if its spinning.>>>>>>>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPEa0Wc9iUc

Comment: @OP - remember you need a collection of tiny Torx screwdrivers and tools to take apart a hard drive without bending or distorting the casing. I have done this as a learning exercise.

Comment: @bonchance90 Just to clarify this, under NO circumstances should you open the physical drive up. You will kill any chances of getting data off of the drive. And while Moab’s line to the YouTube video is interesting, that is really hacky at best. The chances of you even building the enclosure correctly on the first try are — like anything one does for the first time — is very low. And even if you build that and get the drive open, do you even know what two do next? (1/2)

Comment: @bonchance90 My best advice is to leave the drive connected to power and data in whatever case you are using; in your PC or external enclosure. My thinking is that if you let it sit for a while, the drive _might_ power up after a while and then you can use it. Sometimes it is not a motor being stuck, but a capacitor somewhere not holding power until it is powered on for a while. Worth trying! And if that doesn’t work, sorry to say you should consider the drive dead. (2/2)